# lvalue required as increment operand error with old C code

Tags: c

I get lvalue required as increment operand error message with gcc-4.7 for

```
void func1()
{
    u32 *src;
    hwrcolor c;

    c = *(((u32*)src)++);
}
```

and

```
void func2()
{
    u8 *dest;
    hwrcolor c;
    u32 * u32Dest;

    *(((u32 *)dest)++) = c;
}
```

I change them to

```
void func1()
{
    u32 *src;
    hwrcolor c;

    u32Dest = ((u32*)src);
    //c = *(u32Dest ++);
    *u32Dest = *u32Dest + 1;
    c = *u32Dest;
}
```

and

```
void func2()
{
    u8 *dest;
    hwrcolor c;
    u32 * u32Dest;

    u32Dest = ((u32 *)dest);
    //*(u32Dest++) = c;
    *u32Dest = *u32Dest + 1;
    *u32Dest = c;
}
```

source code can be compiled but application not work as expected. Are conversions true?

Comment: What is `u32`,  `u8`, `hwrcolor` ?

Comment: "application not work as expected", what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: @user4757345 Conversion operators including cast give values converted to specified type. So even this code snippet int x = 10; int y; y = ( ( int )x )++; will not compile.

Comment: You should study the difference between `*(p++);` and `(*p)++;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code:

```
((T *)p)++
```

is illegal because `++` may only be applied to an lvalue.

This is because the side-effect of `++` is to increment the value stored in a variable, but `(T *)p` isn't a variable; it's a temporary result of converting `p` to a new type.

This is the same sort of error as `int x = 5;  (x + 3)++;` . It doesn't make sense.

In some older compilers, the code `((T *)p)++;` was accepted and treated like:

```
(*(T **)&p)++;
```

In other words, the memory location storing `p` was treated as if it actually stored a pointer of another type, and then that pointer is incremented. This worked on those compilers because those compilers only ran on hardware where all pointers are stored in the same way.

---

The fix for your `func1` is simply to write `c = *src++;` .  No casts are necessary because `src` is already the right type.

In `func2` the code `*(((u32 *)dest)++) = c;` could be replaced with:

```
*(*(u32 **)&dest)++ = c;
```

Your version doesn't work because you never increment the original `dest`. In fact in both of your attempts you increment the data being pointed to, whereas the original code increments the pointer, leaving the data untouched.

Note that `func2` violates the strict aliasing rule. Older compilers did not optimize based on the strict aliasing rule, but recent versions of gcc do. You should use the flag `-fno-strict-aliasing` when compiling this code.